# Need help in fixing this Elastic watcher alert using a painless script

Tags: elasticsearch, alert, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-watcher

I'm attempting to build a watcher alert in Elastic (hosted cloud version) that will allow me to alert on high jvm memory pressure.

The data is already in elastic, I can retrieve it if I remove the "logic portions" and reported as the following 8 values:

1. memory_max_g1_survivor_space
2. memory_max_g1_eden_space
3. memory_max_g1_old_gen
4. memory_used_g1_survivor_space
5. memory_used_g1_eden_space
6. memory_used_g1_old_gen
7. host.name
8. service.name

I can successfully retrieve these values if I only query them.  But my issue is that I need to determine if it's over 90% and if so alert.

This is the current iteration, and it's giving a compile error, and I'm not sure why, or hot to triage as it will only tell me "compile error" and no other details.

If I remove the "actions" and "transform" the proper documents will retrieve from Elastic.  Reading their docs, I've figured out that I need to use a transform (to manipulate the data into a usable subset), a condition (to trigger if data is found over 90%), and an action to actually fire if the condition is met.

This should retrieve the documents in question (this works), for each document retrieved check the heap pressure utilization (the query in the code below - used/max *100), and if over 90 fire an email off.

I'm brand new to this, and as it seems this is json with embedded java code (the "painless script") ... I cannot find an editor that can understand this and help me fix this.  (Suggestions welcome here if there is any tooling to help detangle this)

The code giving me errors:

```json
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "1m"
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "indices": [
          "metrics-prod-*"
        ],
        "body": {
          "aggs": {
            "by_service": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "host.name.keyword",
                "size": 100
              }
            }
          },
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                      "gte": "now-10m",
                      "lte": "now"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "filter": [
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "name": "jvm_memory"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "transform": {
    "script": {
    "source": """
      def[] heap_pressure_values;
      for (def i = 0; def mues = {{ctx.payload.hits.hits.[i]._source.memory_used_g1_eden_space}}, def muog = {{ctx.payload.hits.hits.[i]._source.memory_used_g1_old_gen}}, def muss = {{ctx.payload.hits.hits.[i]._source.memory_used_g1_survivor_space}}, def mmes = {{ctx.payload.hits.hits.[i]._source.memory_max_g1_eden_space}}, def mmog = {{ctx.payload.hits.hits.[i]._source.memory_max_g1_old_gen}}, def mmss = {{ctx.payload.hits.hits.[i]._source.memory_max_g1_survivor_space}}, i < ctx.payload.hits.hits._source.length; i++) {  
          if ((((mues+muog+muss) / (mmes+mmog+mmss)) * 100) > 90) {
              def value = ((mues+muog+muss) / (mmes+mmog+mmss)) * 100;
              def hostName = {{ctx.payload.hits.hits.[i]._source.host.name}};
              def serviceName = {{ctx.payload.hits.hits.[i]._source.service.name}};
              heap_pressure_values.add(value, hostName, serviceName);
          } else {
            def no_value = 0;
          }
      }
      return heap_pressure_values;
      """
    }
  },
  "actions": {
    "my-logging-action": {
      "condition": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "ctx.metadata.heap_pressure_values.size() > 0"
        }
      },
      "logging": {
        "text": "ctx.metadata.heap_pressure_values.values",
        "level": "warn"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The complete error output it gives me:

[image: ''' Simulation results Cannot simulate watch compile error ''']

And the data returned by a query of our dataset - This is what I'm attempting to alert on, and retrieves properly - Some fields redacted that are not used / relevant:

```json
{
  "watch_id": "_inlined_",
  "node": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "state": "executed",
  "user": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "status": {
    "state": {
      "active": true,
      "timestamp": "2022-06-01T19:06:48.934Z"
    },
    "last_checked": "2022-06-01T19:06:48.934Z",
    "last_met_condition": "2022-06-01T19:06:48.934Z",
    "actions": {},
    "execution_state": "executed",
    "version": -1
  },
  "trigger_event": {
    "type": "manual",
    "triggered_time": "2022-06-01T19:06:48.934Z",
    "manual": {
      "schedule": {
        "scheduled_time": "2022-06-01T19:06:48.934Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "metrics-prod-*"
        ],
        "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
        "body": {
          "aggs": {
            "by_service": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "host.name.keyword",
                "size": 100
              }
            }
          },
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                      "gte": "now-10m",
                      "lte": "now"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ],
              "filter": [
                {
                  "match_phrase": {
                    "name": "jvm_memory"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "condition": {
    "always": {}
  },
  "metadata": {
    "name": "Prod JVM Heap Pressure Warning",
    "xpack": {
      "type": "json"
    }
  },
  "result": {
    "execution_time": "2022-06-01T19:06:48.934Z",
    "execution_duration": 968,
    "input": {
      "type": "search",
      "status": "success",
      "payload": {
        "_shards": {
          "total": 64,
          "failed": 0,
          "successful": 64,
          "skipped": 0
        },
        "hits": {
          "hits": [
            {
              "_index": "metrics-prod-2022-06",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_source": {
                "memory_committed_metaspace": 245018624,
                "memory_max_g1_survivor_space": -1,
                "type": "gauge",
                "sequenceId": 10945,
                "memory_committed_g1_eden_space": 121399934976,
                "memory_max_metaspace": -1,
                "service.type": "fpa-backend",
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_used_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 87202944,
                "memory_committed_g1_survivor_space": 1409286144,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_nmethods": 8773632,
                "memory_used_metaspace": 235112280,
                "memory_max_g1_old_gen": 418759311360,
                "host.name": "api5-prod",
                "memory_max_g1_eden_space": -1,
                "memory_max_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_used_g1_survivor_space": 1409286144,
                "memory_used_g1_eden_space": 7985954816,
                "service.name": "api5-fpa-backend",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 93454336,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 93428096,
                "memory_committed_g1_old_gen": 295950090240,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_nmethods": 1789568,
                "@timestamp": "2022-06-01T19:06:25.924Z",
                "memory_used_g1_old_gen": 187521906064,
                "name": "jvm_memory",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_nmethods": 5701632,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 88866816
              },
              "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "_score": 1
            },
            {
              "_index": "metrics-prod-2022-06",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_source": {
                "memory_committed_metaspace": 133201920,
                "memory_max_g1_survivor_space": -1,
                "type": "gauge",
                "sequenceId": 10936,
                "memory_committed_g1_eden_space": 3372220416,
                "memory_max_metaspace": -1,
                "service.type": "fpa-shared",
                "memory_used_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 49291520,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 122912768,
                "memory_used_compressed_class_space": 14317552,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_nmethods": 5836800,
                "memory_committed_g1_survivor_space": 12582912,
                "memory_used_metaspace": 128057776,
                "memory_max_g1_old_gen": 21474836480,
                "host.name": "api0-prod",
                "memory_max_g1_eden_space": -1,
                "memory_used_g1_survivor_space": 12582912,
                "memory_max_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 122908672,
                "memory_used_g1_eden_space": 2847932416,
                "service.name": "fpa-shared",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 52822016,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 51804160,
                "memory_committed_g1_old_gen": 1992294400,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_nmethods": 1549440,
                "@timestamp": "2022-06-01T19:06:26.719Z",
                "memory_used_g1_old_gen": 210182944,
                "memory_max_compressed_class_space": 1073741824,
                "name": "jvm_memory",
                "memory_committed_compressed_class_space": 16199680,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_nmethods": 2555904,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 54460416
              },
              "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "_score": 1
            },
            {
              "_index": "metrics-prod-2022-06",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_source": {
                "memory_committed_metaspace": 243269632,
                "memory_max_g1_survivor_space": -1,
                "type": "gauge",
                "sequenceId": 10947,
                "memory_committed_g1_eden_space": 52848230400,
                "memory_max_metaspace": -1,
                "service.type": "fpa-backend",
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_used_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 85598464,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_nmethods": 8773632,
                "memory_committed_g1_survivor_space": 1207959552,
                "memory_used_metaspace": 233772080,
                "memory_max_g1_old_gen": 418759311360,
                "host.name": "api4-prod",
                "memory_max_g1_eden_space": -1,
                "memory_max_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_used_g1_survivor_space": 1207959552,
                "memory_used_g1_eden_space": 20703084544,
                "service.name": "api4-fpa-backend",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 95158272,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 95012352,
                "memory_committed_g1_old_gen": 364703121408,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_nmethods": 1787264,
                "@timestamp": "2022-06-01T19:06:27.236Z",
                "memory_used_g1_old_gen": 187802866888,
                "name": "jvm_memory",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_nmethods": 4849664,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 87949312
              },
              "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "_score": 1
            },
            {
              "_index": "metrics-prod-2022-06",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_source": {
                "memory_committed_metaspace": 256114688,
                "memory_max_g1_survivor_space": -1,
                "type": "gauge",
                "sequenceId": 10935,
                "memory_committed_g1_eden_space": 187535720448,
                "memory_max_metaspace": -1,
                "service.type": "fpa-backend",
                "memory_used_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 86692992,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_committed_g1_survivor_space": 1543503872,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_nmethods": 8773632,
                "memory_used_metaspace": 245723584,
                "memory_max_g1_old_gen": 418759311360,
                "host.name": "api6-prod",
                "memory_max_g1_eden_space": -1,
                "memory_used_g1_survivor_space": 1543503872,
                "memory_max_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_used_g1_eden_space": 63820529664,
                "service.name": "api6-fpa-backend",
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 107003392,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 107020288,
                "memory_committed_g1_old_gen": 229680087040,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_nmethods": 1844352,
                "@timestamp": "2022-06-01T19:04:03.306Z",
                "memory_used_g1_old_gen": 193096379968,
                "name": "jvm_memory",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_nmethods": 4980736,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 88342528
              },
              "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "_score": 1
            },
            {
              "_index": "metrics-prod-2022-06",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_source": {
                "memory_committed_metaspace": 245628928,
                "memory_max_g1_survivor_space": -1,
                "type": "gauge",
                "sequenceId": 13888,
                "memory_committed_g1_eden_space": 67343745024,
                "memory_max_metaspace": -1,
                "service.type": "fpa-backend",
                "memory_used_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 87726208,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_committed_g1_survivor_space": 704643072,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_nmethods": 8773632,
                "memory_used_metaspace": 236316808,
                "memory_max_g1_old_gen": 429496729600,
                "host.name": "api8-prod",
                "memory_max_g1_eden_space": -1,
                "memory_used_g1_survivor_space": 704643072,
                "memory_max_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_used_g1_eden_space": 34191966208,
                "service.name": "api8-fpa-backend",
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 101222400,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 101711872,
                "memory_committed_g1_old_gen": 361448341504,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_nmethods": 1786880,
                "@timestamp": "2022-06-01T19:04:04.210Z",
                "memory_used_g1_old_gen": 195107831232,
                "name": "jvm_memory",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_nmethods": 5177344,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 91881472
              },
              "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "_score": 1
            },
            {
              "_index": "metrics-prod-2022-06",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_source": {
                "memory_committed_metaspace": 246591488,
                "memory_max_g1_survivor_space": -1,
                "type": "gauge",
                "sequenceId": 10919,
                "memory_committed_g1_eden_space": 20937965568,
                "memory_max_metaspace": -1,
                "service.type": "fpa-backend",
                "memory_used_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 89098624,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_committed_g1_survivor_space": 1073741824,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_nmethods": 8773632,
                "memory_used_metaspace": 237059432,
                "memory_max_g1_old_gen": 418759311360,
                "host.name": "api2-prod",
                "memory_max_g1_eden_space": -1,
                "memory_used_g1_survivor_space": 1073741824,
                "memory_max_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_used_g1_eden_space": 12884901888,
                "service.name": "api2-fpa-backend",
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 97661312,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 97845248,
                "memory_committed_g1_old_gen": 396747603968,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_nmethods": 1804416,
                "@timestamp": "2022-06-01T19:04:19.920Z",
                "memory_used_g1_old_gen": 183998486016,
                "name": "jvm_memory",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_nmethods": 4784128,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 91947008
              },
              "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "_score": 1
            },
            {
              "_index": "metrics-prod-2022-06",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_source": {
                "memory_committed_metaspace": 247201792,
                "memory_max_g1_survivor_space": -1,
                "type": "gauge",
                "sequenceId": 10911,
                "memory_committed_g1_eden_space": 196326981632,
                "memory_max_metaspace": -1,
                "service.type": "fpa-backend",
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_used_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 89875712,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_nmethods": 8773632,
                "memory_committed_g1_survivor_space": 167772160,
                "memory_used_metaspace": 236621976,
                "memory_max_g1_old_gen": 418759311360,
                "host.name": "api1-prod",
                "memory_max_g1_eden_space": -1,
                "memory_max_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_used_g1_survivor_space": 167772160,
                "memory_used_g1_eden_space": 77108084736,
                "service.name": "api1-fpa-backend",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 97583104,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 97579264,
                "memory_committed_g1_old_gen": 222264557568,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_nmethods": 1807488,
                "@timestamp": "2022-06-01T19:04:16.731Z",
                "memory_used_g1_old_gen": 188840619040,
                "name": "jvm_memory",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_nmethods": 5177344,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 92078080
              },
              "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "_score": 1
            },
            {
              "_index": "metrics-prod-2022-06",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_source": {
                "memory_committed_metaspace": 246329344,
                "memory_max_g1_survivor_space": -1,
                "type": "gauge",
                "sequenceId": 10947,
                "memory_committed_g1_eden_space": 114923929600,
                "memory_max_metaspace": -1,
                "service.type": "fpa-backend",
                "memory_used_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 86866816,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_nmethods": 8773632,
                "memory_committed_g1_survivor_space": 2717908992,
                "memory_used_metaspace": 236733944,
                "memory_max_g1_old_gen": 418759311360,
                "host.name": "api3-prod",
                "memory_max_g1_eden_space": -1,
                "memory_used_g1_survivor_space": 2717908992,
                "memory_max_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_used_g1_eden_space": 63216549888,
                "service.name": "api3-fpa-backend",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 96403456,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 96372096,
                "memory_committed_g1_old_gen": 301117472768,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_nmethods": 1789824,
                "@timestamp": "2022-06-01T19:04:15.370Z",
                "memory_used_g1_old_gen": 197162180080,
                "name": "jvm_memory",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_nmethods": 5177344,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 88145920
              },
              "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "_score": 1
            },
            {
              "_index": "metrics-prod-2022-06",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_source": {
                "memory_committed_metaspace": 252706816,
                "memory_max_g1_survivor_space": -1,
                "type": "gauge",
                "sequenceId": 13895,
                "memory_committed_g1_eden_space": 191998459904,
                "memory_max_metaspace": -1,
                "service.type": "fpa-backend",
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_used_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 88067072,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_nmethods": 8773632,
                "memory_committed_g1_survivor_space": 268435456,
                "memory_used_metaspace": 242709496,
                "memory_max_g1_old_gen": 418759311360,
                "host.name": "api7-prod",
                "memory_max_g1_eden_space": -1,
                "memory_max_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_used_g1_survivor_space": 268435456,
                "memory_used_g1_eden_space": 128849018880,
                "service.name": "api7-fpa-backend",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 105381888,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 105210496,
                "memory_committed_g1_old_gen": 226492416000,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_nmethods": 1809024,
                "@timestamp": "2022-06-01T19:05:02.265Z",
                "memory_used_g1_old_gen": 190759635976,
                "name": "jvm_memory",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_nmethods": 5767168,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 91095040
              },
              "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "_score": 1
            },
            {
              "_index": "metrics-prod-2022-06",
              "_type": "_doc",
              "_source": {
                "memory_committed_metaspace": 256114688,
                "memory_max_g1_survivor_space": -1,
                "type": "gauge",
                "sequenceId": 10936,
                "memory_committed_g1_eden_space": 187535720448,
                "memory_max_metaspace": -1,
                "service.type": "fpa-backend",
                "memory_used_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 86692992,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_committed_g1_survivor_space": 1543503872,
                "memory_max_codeheap_non_nmethods": 8773632,
                "memory_used_metaspace": 245723584,
                "memory_max_g1_old_gen": 418759311360,
                "host.name": "api6-prod",
                "memory_max_g1_eden_space": -1,
                "memory_used_g1_survivor_space": 1543503872,
                "memory_max_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 121442304,
                "memory_used_g1_eden_space": 64458063872,
                "service.name": "api6-fpa-backend",
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 107003392,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_profiled_nmethods": 107020288,
                "memory_committed_g1_old_gen": 229680087040,
                "memory_used_codeheap_non_nmethods": 1844352,
                "@timestamp": "2022-06-01T19:05:03.287Z",
                "memory_used_g1_old_gen": 193096379968,
                "name": "jvm_memory",
                "memory_committed_codeheap_non_nmethods": 4980736,
                "memory_committed_codeheap_profiled_nmethods": 88342528
              },
              "_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              "_score": 1
            }
          ],
          "total": 90,
          "max_score": 1
        },
        "took": 967,
        "timed_out": false,
        "aggregations": {
          "by_service": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "doc_count": 10,
                "key": "api0-prod"
              },
              {
                "doc_count": 10,
                "key": "api1-prod"
              },
              {
                "doc_count": 10,
                "key": "api2-prod"
              },
              {
                "doc_count": 10,
                "key": "api3-prod"
              },
              {
                "doc_count": 10,
                "key": "api4-prod"
              },
              {
                "doc_count": 10,
                "key": "api5-prod"
              },
              {
                "doc_count": 10,
                "key": "api6-prod"
              },
              {
                "doc_count": 10,
                "key": "api7-prod"
              },
              {
                "doc_count": 10,
                "key": "api8-prod"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "search": {
        "request": {
          "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
          "indices": [
            "metrics-prod-*"
          ],
          "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
          "body": {
            "aggs": {
              "by_service": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "host.name.keyword",
                  "size": 100
                }
              }
            },
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "@timestamp": {
                        "gte": "now-10m",
                        "lte": "now"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "name": "jvm_memory"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "condition": {
      "type": "always",
      "status": "success",
      "met": true
    },
    "actions": []
  },
  "messages": []
}
```

Comment: You should try using the API to execute your watch https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/watcher-api-execute-watch.html, it will give you the full json error that might help you debug

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I was testing this with the simulate functionality that is built into the watcher alert editor.  I'll try using the post / get api via postman and see if I can get different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tldr;

Painless can be a bit difficult to work with.
But here are some suggestions to better understand how to work with it.

- In `Kibana` use the Painless lab tabs, available in the dev tools to write and test the core part of your algorithm
- Use `Debug.explain(variable);` to [debug painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-debugging.html)
- Use the [watcher execute API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/watcher-api-execute-watch.html) in the dev tools to run your watcher instead of the UI.

## Fix

```json
PUT /_watcher/watch/_execute
{
  "watch": {
    "trigger": {
      "schedule": {
        "interval": "1m"
      }
    },
    "input": {
      "search": {
        "request": {
          "indices": [
            "72467068"
          ],
          "body": {
            "aggs": {
              "by_service": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "host.name.keyword",
                  "size": 100
                }
              }
            },
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "match_phrase": {
                      "name": "jvm_memory"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "transform": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
      def heap_pressure_values = new ArrayList();
      
      for (def i = 0; i < ctx.payload.hits.hits.length; i++) {
        def mues = ctx.payload.hits.hits[i]._source.memory_used_g1_eden_space;
        def muog = ctx.payload.hits.hits[i]._source.memory_used_g1_old_gen;
        def muss = ctx.payload.hits.hits[i]._source.memory_used_g1_survivor_space;
        def mmes = ctx.payload.hits.hits[i]._source.memory_max_g1_eden_space;
        def mmog = ctx.payload.hits.hits[i]._source.memory_max_g1_old_gen;
        def mmss = ctx.payload.hits.hits[i]._source.memory_max_g1_survivor_space;
        
        if ((((mues+muog+muss) / (mmes+mmog+mmss)) * 100) > 90) {
            def hit = new HashMap();
            
            hit["value"] = ((mues+muog+muss) / (mmes+mmog+mmss)) * 100;
            hit ["hostName"] = ctx.payload.hits.hits[i]._source["host.name"];
            hit ["serviceName"] = ctx.payload.hits.hits[i]._source["service.name"];
            
            heap_pressure_values.add(hit);
        } else {
          def no_value = 0;
        }
      }
      return heap_pressure_values;
      """
      }
    },
    "actions": {
      "my-logging-action": {
        "condition": {
          "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": "ctx.payload._value.size() > 0"
          }
        },
        "logging": {
          "text": "{{ctx.payload._value}}",
          "level": "warn"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the assist.  Since posting this I've been slowly figuring out how to debug things.  I actually did find the Debug.explain functionality, and that got me about 90% of the way there (though nowhere near as elegantly as what you have above).  

The last bit I was hung up on was understanding how to parse a field with a period in the name like ["host.name"].  It was not readily apparent from the docs how to do this, only that painless could do it.  I'm going to test this asap, and hopefully this is the last tidbit I was missing.

Comment: Was able to confirm this does work.  Paulo you got me the rest of the way, and I don't think I would've ever found out how to access a "."  field name without you.  Now though I have my watcher, and it's making sure we're safe.